# Is there any relationship between $\mathcal{l}^p$ spaces and $\mathcal{L}^P$ space?

Tags: notation, lp-spaces

Due to the similarity of the names, I guessed that there may be some relationship between the two spaces.

Is there such a relationship, or is there nothing more to it other than the fact that they both use the same letter, one upper and the other lower case?

Comment: For $p=2$ think Fourier.

Comment: You can define $L^p$ spaces on any measure space. If the measure is counting measure on some set you get an $\ell^p$ space.

Comment: $l^p(\mathbb{Z})$ is the subspace of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ of functions constant on each $(n,n+1)$ interval